# phrase search in meteor search-source package

Tags: regex, search, meteor

I have a meteor app for which I added the search-source package to search certain collections and it works partially. That is, when I search for the term `foo bar` it returns results for each of "foo" and "bar". This is fine, but I want to also be able to wrap the terms in quotes this way: `"foo bar"` and get results for an exact match only. at the moment when i do this i get an empty set. Here is my server code:

```
//Server.js
SearchSource.defineSource('FruitBasket', function(searchText, options) {  
    // options = options || {}; // to be sure that options is at least an empty object
    if(searchText) {
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
    var selector = {$or: [
      {'fruit.name': regExp},
      {'fruit.season': regExp},
      {'fruit.treeType': regExp}
    ]};

    return Basket.find(selector, options).fetch();
  } else {
    return Basket.find({}, options).fetch();
  }
});

function buildRegExp(searchText) {
  // this is a dumb implementation
  var parts = searchText.trim().split(/[ \-\:]+/);
  return new RegExp("(" + parts.join('|') + ")", "ig");
}
```

and my client code:

```
//Client.js
Template.dispResults.helpers({

  getPackages_fruit: function() {
    return PackageSearch_fruit.getData({
      transform: function(matchText, regExp) {
        return matchText.replace(regExp, "<b>$&</b>")
      },
      sort: {isoScore: -1}
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the `.split` pattern so that it ignores everything between double quotes.

```
/[ \-\:]+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/
```

Thus, you can simply wrap an exact phrase search in double quotes and it won't get split.
There is one more thing; since we don't need the quotes, they are removed in the next line using a `.map` function with a regex that replaces double quotes at the start or the end of a string part: `/^"|"$/`

Sample code:

```js
function buildRegExp(searchText) {
  // exact phrase search in double quotes won't get split  
  var arr = searchText.trim().split(/[ \-\:]+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)/);
  var parts = arr.map(function(x){return x.replace(/^"|"$/g, '');});
  return new RegExp("(" + parts.join('|') + ")", "ig");
}
console.log(buildRegExp("foo bar"));
console.log(buildRegExp("\"foo bar\""));
```